# How to solve this linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need help in solving this recurrence relation.

$F(n) = 2F(n-1) + 3F(n-2) + n*7^n$

I truly have no idea of where to start with because of this term $n*7^n$

Comment: What is $$n\cdot 7^n$$?

Comment: It is $$a_n=c_1 (-1)^n+c_2 3^n-\frac{1}{256} 7^{n+2} \left(8
   (-1)^{2 n} n-16 n+9 (-1)^{2 n}-4\right)$$

Comment: Sir but how to get this equation??

Comment: At first you must solve $$F_n=2F_{n-1}+3F_{n-1}$$ by setting $$F_n=q^n$$